# How to identify keyboard down key stroke in iPad

Tags: objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch

I am developing an ipad application . Getting user information through a form and it contains multiple UITextfeilds inside a scrollView.Now i want to identify the keyboard down key stroke to arrange the form if user left it in middle . Not sure i can make use of ascii value ..any body knows the ascii value for keyboard down .
Any help appreciated .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using `textFieldDidEndEditing` method of the `<UITextFieldDelegate>`